# Kafka Stream aggregate function sinking each joined record in an incremental way, instead of a single list of aggregated records

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I’m having some issues with my Kafka Streams implementation in production. I’ve implemented a function that takes a `KTable` and a `KStream`, and yields another `KTable` with aggregated results based on the join of these two inputs. The idea is to iterate a list in the `KStream` input, and for each iteration, join it with the `KTable`, and aggregate into a list of events present in the `KTable` and sink to a topic, containing the original `KTable` event and the list of joined `KStream` (1 to N join).

###### Context

[image: wanted topology]

This is how my component interacts with its context. `MovementEvent` contains a list of `transaction_ids` that should match the `transaction_id` of `TransactionEvent`, where the joiner should match & generate a new event (`Sinked Event`) with the original `MovementEvent` and a list of the matched `TransactionEvent`.

For reference, the Movement topic has 12 million, while the Transaction topic has 21 million records.

###### Implementation

```java
public class SinkEventProcessor implements BiFunction<
        KTable<TransactionKey, Transaction>,
        KStream<String, Movement>,
        KTable<SinkedEventKey, SinkedEvent>> {

    @Override
    public KTable<SinkedEventKey, SinkedEvent> apply(final KTable<TransactionKey, Transaction> transactionTable,
                                                     final KStream<String, Movement> movementStream) {
        return movementStream
                // [A]
                .flatMap((movementKey, movement) -> movement
                        .getTransactionIds()
                        .stream()
                        .distinct()
                        .map(transactionId -> new KeyValue<>(
                                TransactionKey.newBuilder()
                                        .setTransactionId(transactionId)
                                        .build(),
                                movement))
                        .toList())
                // [B]
                .join(transactionTable, (movement, transaction) -> Pair.newBuilder()
                        .setMovement(movement)
                        .setTransaction(transaction)
                        .build())
                // [C]
                .groupBy((transactionKey, pair) -> SinkedEventKey.newBuilder()
                        .setMovementId(pair.getMovement().getMovementId())
                        .build())
                // [D]
                .aggregate(SinkedEvent::new, (key, pair, collectable) ->
                        collectable.setMovement(pair.getMovement())
                                .addTransaction(pair.getTransaction()));
    }
}
```

[A] I have started the implementation by iterating the `Movement KStream`, extracting the transactionId and creating a `TransactionKey` to use as the new key for the following operation, to facilitate the join with each `transactionId` present in the `Movement` entity. This operation returns a `KStream<TransactionKey, Movement>`

[B] Joins the formerly transformed `KStream` and adds each value to an intermediate pair. Returns a `KStream<TransactionKey, Pair>.

[C] Groups the pairs by `movementId` and constructs the new key (`SinkedEventKey`) for the sink operation.

[D] Aggregates into the result object (`SinkedEvent`) by adding the `transaction` to the list. This operation will also sink to the topic as a `KTable<SinkedEventKey, SinkedEvent>`

##### Problem

The problem starts when we start processing the stream, the sink operation of the processor starts generating more records than it should. For instance, for a Movement with 4 `transaction_id`, the output topic will become something like this:

| partition | offset | count of [TransactionEvent] | expected count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 0 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 0 | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 0 | 4 | 4 | 4 |

And the same happens for other records (e.g. a Movement with 13 `transaction_id` will yield 13 menssages). So for some reason that I can't compreehend, the `aggregate` operation is sinking on each operation, instead of waiting and collecting into the list and sinking only once.

I've tried to reproduce it in a development cluster, with exactly the same settings, with no avail. Everything seems to be working properly when I try to reproduce it (a Movement with 8 transactions produces only 1 record) but whenever I bring it to production it doesn't work as intended. I'm not sure what I'm missing, any help?